# Is it possible to unearn a hat in Winter Bash?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash

I was thinking: Are users able to unearn hats in Winter Bash?

Let's say I was going to delete the answer I did in order to get the Snaphat hat, will I lose the Snaphat hat? (P.S.: Of course I won't do that, that was just a example...)

I am just curious if that would happen or not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it's not. Unless we manually reset hats, you keep them.

Comment: [Example: the Vexillologist hat](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403778/did-a-gust-of-wind-make-me-lose-my-hat/403779#403779)

Comment: Two other examples: [Balalaïka and Disciple](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403787/can-we-lose-hats/403789#403789)